# WCF - (504) The server did not return a response for this request

Tags: asp.net, wcf, timeout, request

I have a JSONP WCF service,using back end as MySql.It is working properly when i run it locally with visual studio.

Now we have hosted it in Windows Server 2003.

Now there is very strange problem occurring..

When I do a request with fiddler which does not require much processing internally, it gives me result 200 OK with desired output as response, But when I do a request which requires some internal data processing, it gives me 504 error(gateway time out error).

I also looked at C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles to see if it logs any error but it shows ok result in fiddler request which is as follows:

## Fields: date time s-sitename s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status

2010-04-07 10:08:06 W3SVC490896353 s-ip GET /InitialState.svc/GetInitialState reference=1&pageId=18 8080 - c-ip Fiddler 200 0 64

Can anyone please help me to resolve the problem ??
Or any ideas i can try to find out why it is happening ??
Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a timeout on the client side, or on something between the server and the client.

Things to check:

- Are you using a proxy server? Is there a timeout set on it?
- How are you making the call from the client? What is the timeout setting on the client side?

Comment: Shiraz thanx for your help..
I want to tell one more thing the same application was worknig perfect fine at other server(Windows Server 2008). Tried to find out everything but didn't help.

It would be great if you can provide more details how to check these things.

Waiting for your reply.......